# Normalization for telephone support worker

Tags: database-design, normalization, database-normalization

I am creating a sql database which logs calls from companies (or separate departments within a company) with service contracts(1).

An initial call is logged  by a **first line support analyst** who assesses the severity of the problem and places the call in a pool. The call is picked up by a **problem analyst** who in turn allocates it to a **specialist analyst** based on their expertise, who will endeavour to provide a solution.  This process is overseen by a **support manager**.

This is how far i have got with normalizing the data. I'm not sure if i have chose the correct initial key. Also i'm not sure how to finish the 3rd normal form. Here is a picture of it.

[image: Normalization]

If any of you guys could help me i would be fantastic

*UPDATE
OK i have had another go at normalizing it and here it is:
(star = Foreign Key. double star = Primary Key)

```
**Call id**
Date and time of call
Method of call
*First line Support Analyst ID
*Problem Analyst  ID
*Specialist Analysts  ID
*Service contract number
Name of caller
landline
mobile 
Email address
Brief textual description of problem
Initial severity level

**Action id** 
*Call id 
Date and time of action
Textual description of action
Current status
Current severity level

**Specialist Analysts  ID**
Name of specialist analyst
Expertise

**First line Support Analyst ID**
Name of first line support analyst

**Problem Analyst ID**
Name of problem analyst

**Service contract number**
Company
Department
Software product
Software version
Operating system
```

---

NOTES

(1)  A service contract relates either to a company as a whole or to a department, i.e. two departments in the same company will have separate service contracts, A service contract covers a distinct software/OS combination, so SQL Developer under Windows 7 would have a separate service contract to SQL Developer under Windows XP (or Windows Vista or MacOS Lion)

Comment: What do you understand your goal to be in moving from 2NF to 3NF?

Comment: I have added an updated version of the normalization. does this look correct to 3NF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your requirements, it's hard to be precise, but here are some notes:

I would create an "analyst" table, with analyst_type, rather than seperate tables for each type of analyst.

I would have a none-to-many relationship between analysts and expertise areas.

I would create the explicit concept of "call_status", rather than depend on which analyst currently has the ball.

I would consider having call_status, action and current_analyst in a separate table with date_time flags, so you can track history - when was it assigned to the 2nd line analyst? How long did they have the call? What did they do?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have done most of what you have said. With regards to call_status it can be i) awaiting assignment ii) being worked on iii) awaiting reply iv) closed. This is held in 'Current Status'. Would it be more appropriate to store this in the 'Call' table? Here is a link to the updated normalization [Normalization-redone](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/7804/normalization.jpg)

Comment: I think there's a many-to-many between analysts and expertise.
I think the analystID should be on the action table, not the call table.

Comment: [Updated](http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/7804/normalization.jpg) Does that look normalized now? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You still need a "many to many" between analysts and expertise - typically this requires a "join" table, with analyst_id and expertise_id as foreign keys.